# how to set mat-mini-fab in the 'below after' like matBadge

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to display the mat-mini-fab button in the corner of another button like matBadge style

example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prtfqp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.html

The reason why I do not simply use the matBadge is because i want it to be clickable
like a button.

if there is a way to make matBadge clickable and run a function with the `(click)` attribute - it also a good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to add "+" before value?
Why not use second button from your example with '+' before value, e.g :

```
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary"
   matBadge="+8" matBadgePosition="below after" matBadgeColor="accent">
     Action
  </button>
```

or for value from ts file:

```
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary"
   [matBadge]="'+' + value" matBadgePosition="below after" matBadgeColor="accent">
     Action
  </button>
```

Edited after changed question:

1. Added sample class for button and mat-icon:

   ```
          <button mat-mini-fab color="accent" class="custom-mat-mini-fab" 
           aria-label="Example icon button with a plus one icon">
             <mat-icon style="icon24" class="custom-mat-icon">
               plus_one
             </mat-icon>
          </button>
   ```
2. Added example styles:

   ```
         .custom-mat-mini-fab {
           position: absolute;
           top: 25px;
           left: 70px; 
           width: 20px;
           height: 20px;
           display: flex;
           align-items: center;
           justify-content: center;
         }

         .custom-mat-icon {
           font-size: 18px;
           display: flex;
           align-items: center;
           justify-content: center;
         }
   ```

Also if you want to call only nested button method (without calling parent button method too) you need to add $event.stopPropagation() method .e.g:

```
           (click)="onMatMiniFabClicked(); $event.stopPropagation()"
```

Comment: I edited my question.
I need to activate a function by clicking on the mini-fab button.